# C WIN32 close std handle or not

Tags: c, winapi

after using 'GetStdHandle(...)', should I use 'CloseHandle()' to close the generated handle for input or output or not?
for example, which one is true:

```
int main() {

HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(-11);
..
return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main() {

HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(-11);
..
CloseHandle(h);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: no, you not need close this handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) returns an existing handle. The pendent is the function [SetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setstdhandle). You just get the value previously set with `SetStdHandle`. Therefore you must not close the handle.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to close a handle returned by a call to `GetStdHandle()`.